# Converting a table into 3D using the Columns

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, tensor

I have 3 variables and I have data in the following format

[image]

I want to convert this into a 3d matrix(tensor) where in `student_id`, `year` and `course_id` will be the modes of tensor, and `count` will be the value of the triplet combination

```
T[1000,2010,2] = 1
```

Is there a simple `pivot_table` kind of function take values of a specific column create a new dimension. Something like this.

```
df.pivot_table('count', ['Student_id'], 'year')
```

Comment: what is your expected output ....

Comment: a tensor with 3 dimension, student_id,year and course_id will be the 3 dimensions. Here is an image of tensor with 3 modes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QsMD.png

Comment: To be more specific ,Cell in the tensor should have a value 1, if student with specific id, registered for the course in the year, and 0 for all other cells.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors) is what you're looking for?